# Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "ProductNames" of recursive query "CTE"

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

```
With CTE as
(
  Select ProductCategoryId,
         Count(*) [Count], 
         Max(ProductName) ProductNames, 
         0 [Rank] 
  From Product 
  Group By ProductCategoryId 

  Union ALL 

  Select CTE.ProductCategoryId,
         CTE.[Count], 
         ProductNames + N' , ' + ProductName, 
         [Rank]+1 
  From 
    CTE inner join Product 
      on CTE.ProductCategoryId = Product.ProductCategoryId 
      and CTE.ProductNames Not Like '%'+ProductName+'%' 
      and CTE.[Rank] < cte.[Count]
)
Select ProductCategoryId,
       Max(ProductNames) ProductNames,
       Max([Count]) [Count] 
From CTE 
Group by ProductCategoryId 
order by ProductCategoryId
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Is the type of `ProductName`  `NVARCHAR`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've received this error before on string types in recursive CTEs.  I just fix it by casting the value to a big string:

```
  Select ProductCategoryId,
         Count(*) as [Count], 
         cast(Max(ProductName) as nvarchar(max)) as ProductNames, 
         0 as [Rank] 
  From Product 
  Group By ProductCategoryId 

  Union ALL 

  Select CTE.ProductCategoryId,
         CTE.[Count], 
         cast(ProductNames + N' , ' + ProductName as nvarchar(max)), 
         [Rank]+1 
  From 
    CTE inner join Product 
      on CTE.ProductCategoryId = Product.ProductCategoryId 
      and CTE.ProductNames Not Like '%'+ProductName+'%' 
      and CTE.[Rank] < cte.[Count]
```